# Custom Navigation Bar Color by URL ID

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, navbar

I've created a traditional navigation bar. Everything works great, but now I would like to customize the navbar Color by District URL.

**For example:**

```
###blue
http://0.0.0.0:3000/districts/1

###red
http://0.0.0.0:3000/districts/2

###orange
http://0.0.0.0:3000/districts/3

etc.
```

I've currently hacked out a solution, but it isn't that efficient when I add more Districts. I would like to somehow loop through each District and get the associated css_color.

**District Params**

```
:name, :css_color, :photo
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar1 {
  background-color: #4B8DC8;
}

.navbar2 {
  background-color: #406DA6;
}

.navbar3 {
  background-color: #640000;
}

.navbar4 {
  background-color: #1450A3;
}

.navbar5 {
  background-color: #CBAA7F;
}
```

_navigation.html.erb

```
###how can i do this more efficiently
<% if  params[:controller] == 'static_pages' || params[:controller] == 'searches' %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif params[:controller] == 'sessions' %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif params[:controller] == 'password_resets' %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif params[:controller] == 'resource_tags' %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif params[:controller] == 'favorites' %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif @districts %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

###Beg of districts
<% elsif @district.id == 1 %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar1 navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif @district.id == 2 %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar2 navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif @district.id == 3 %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar3 navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif @district.id == 4 %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar4 navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% elsif @district.id == 5 %>
  <nav class="navbar navbar5 navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - it looks like you want the common navbar stuff for all the options. The only difference will be the difference you get if you have districts. So that means you don't need all the guff checking ever kind of controller or session. Just:

```
<% if @district.present? %>
   ... you'll do the district-specific stuff here
<% else %>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% end %>
```

right? no sense in repeating the same code over and over for multiple options, if it's always there.

Now you need to figure out what to put in if you have a district... but your id is already a one-to-one match with your css style_names

navbar1 for district id 1 navbar2 for district id 2 etc...

so you don't need anything more than that id:

```
<% if @district.present? %>
   <nav class="navbar navbar<%= @district.id %> navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% else %>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<% end %>
```

But there's still duplication here. The only thing that differs between the navbar at the top (in the if-clause) and the navbar at the bottom (in the else-clause) is that extra style... so you can cut down the if/else to only surround the difference like this:

```
<nav class="navbar <%= "navbar#{@district.id}" if @district.present? %> navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```